# Python3 - For key in dict read file lines, doesn't working with all items

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, file-io

I take a look on documentation and some questions but I didn't find anything like this.

I have a dictionary and for each item I need to loop an entire file and retrieve some specif values. The interaction works over a DICT -> LIST, but when a try to use a file it doesn't work.

The code:

```
file = open(sys.argv[1], newline='')

print("DICT - FILE")
d= {1:"a",2:"b",3:"c"}
for item in d:
    print("Loop over item =", item)
    for n, line in enumerate(file):
        print("Do something on line =", n)

file.close()

print()

print("DICT - LIST")
l1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for item in d:
    print("Loop over item =", item)
    for n in l1:
        print("Do something on list item =", n)
```

The output:

```
DICT - FILE
Loop over item = 1
Do something on line = 0
Do something on line = 1
Do something on line = 2
Do something on line = 3
Do something on line = 4
Loop over item = 2
Loop over item = 3

DICT - LIST
Loop over item = 1
Do something on list item = [1, 2, 3]
Do something on list item = [4, 5, 6]
Do something on list item = [7, 8, 9]
Loop over item = 2
Do something on list item = [1, 2, 3]
Do something on list item = [4, 5, 6]
Do something on list item = [7, 8, 9]
Loop over item = 3
Do something on list item = [1, 2, 3]
Do something on list item = [4, 5, 6]
Do something on list item = [7, 8, 9]
```

Someone can figure out why the DICT - FILE method doesn't read lines again after Loop over item = 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is an iterator.  `enumerate(file)` exhausts the iterator and there is nothing left to enumerate on subsequent calls.  To reiterate, you must reset the file with file.seek(0).  That could also go before or after the `for...enumerate(file)` statement.

An alternative would be to reopen the file, but seek should work.

I strongly recommend using a with statement to auto-close the file.